# Python: writing to another process's memory under linux

Tags: python, linux, address-space

How to write to another process's address space using python under Ubuntu Linux? 
My attempts:

1) Using the virtual file /proc/$PID/mem and seeking to the address. I have successfully used it to read memory, but attempting to write causes an IOError:

```
fd=open("/proc/"+pid+"/mem","r+")
fd.seek(address,0)
fd.write("ABC")
```

Output:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

2) Attempting to use the python-ptrace library as suggested in other threads. However, I cannot find good documentation or example code.

Note: this is not a permissions issue, running as root produces the same behaviour.

Comment: `rw` is not a valid mode value for `open()`. To open a file for both reading and writing you'd have to use `r+` instead.

Comment: Are you sure it's not more appropriate to use explicit IPC (which can include shared memory btw)?

Comment: Changed 'rw' to 'r+' but I still get an IOError

Comment: What you're attempting is unusual enough that perhaps sharing what it is you're trying to accomplish would get a better answer, instead of asking about the execution of your presupposed solution.

Comment: @BrianCain No, I am working with closed source binaries so proper IPC is not possible.

Comment: Is ther other process a python process? A kernel process? Need more info.

Comment: @ZippyZeppoli The other process is a standard userspace process, albeit closed-source.

Comment: @CaptainMurphy I am trying to modify some strings in a running closed-source application, to replace all instances of 'XYZ' with 'ABC'. By sending SIGSTOP to the process and reading /proc/$PID/maps and /proc/$PID/mem, I have managed to obtain the addresses of all such strings. But I need a way to write to the addresses.

Comment: Try using low-level IO instead (os.read, os.write) using the fd. Not sure if that will help with this problem, but is generally better in this case.

Comment: @Keith This just changes the error to `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`

Comment: What flags are you using?

Comment: Did you see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution here: http://tito.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2/trunk/draft/fakefs.py

It uses the ctypes package to load libc, then libc.ptrace with the POKEDATA option to write the bytes.